# How to trigger buttons after typing something with enter in toast notifications uwp

Tags: uwp, notifications, toast

In quick reply toast notification if i write a quick reply and want to send it, I have to to press reply after having typed, is it possible to make 'Enter' trigger that button?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such API in UWP to support the operation that triggers a button after typing something with **Enter** in toast notification.

The default behavior of **Enter** is to insert a new line in a input box. And there is a built-in hot key(**Ctrl+Enter**) on a toast button which you could view in the [sample](https://github.com/WindowsNotifications/quickstart-sending-local-toast-win10) (the first toast button in `MainPage.xaml.cs`).

**Update:**

You could refer to the official sample [Quickstart-Sending-Local-Toast](https://github.com/WindowsNotifications/quickstart-sending-local-toast-win10/tree/master/Quickstart-Sending-Local-Toast) for the full code. In the sample code, you could see the first `ToastButton` instance has a **Ctrl+ Enter** shortcut.

The key point is that the value of [ToastButton.TextBoxId](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.toolkit.uwp.notifications.toastbutton.textboxid?view=win-comm-toolkit-dotnet-stable) property must be the same as the value of `Id` property of the `ToastTextBox` control(set the `Id` property when using constructor `ToastTextBox(String)`).

Comment: is it possible to disable a button once the user types anything in the reply textbox?

Comment: There is no API supported to disable a toast button in Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.Notifications package.

Comment: also Ctrl + Enter is also not working..is there any specific thing i have to do to make it work?

Comment: I have updated the answer, you could view if the update could meet your requirements.

Comment: Yeah but in that case Reply button comes after TextBox. I can't change UI.

Comment: It is a built-in behavior that a ToastButton's TextBoxId with the same value as the ToastTextBox's Id  will be to the right of the ToastTextBox control. You could change the content of the button, but it is not supported to change the position of the button.